# Can't free up port 80, no matter what I try

Tags: ports

Trying to get WAMP working again, and testing to see that the Apache server is working. It keep saying port 80 is being used by Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 - I've removed IIS, I've removed SQL Server 2008, etc, etc, etc - I can't find anything that would be causing this!

What else could it be other than SQL Server 2008 and IIS?

Comment: Netstat -a should tell whats listening/established on that port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open a command prompt using "run as administrator" and type `netstat -ab`

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             Computername:0         LISTENING
 [httpd.exe]
```

You can then find httpd.exe (or whatever program is listening on port 80)

If you use `netstat -ao` it will tell you the process id,

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             Computername:0         LISTENING       4872
```

You can then find this process-id (PID) in Task Manager (check the "services" tab)

[image: Task Manager]

Comment: It says "Cannot find ownership information"

Comment: PID is 4, however there is no "4" in the services tab of task manager.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander: Ah - that's "System"/"Services" (see output of  `taskslist` command). Which isn't helpful (at least to me) in working out what is using port 80. I'm out of ideas.